# Word Numbered List Issue -- within tables & boxes

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it asking too much of word to renumber lists within tables within inserted objects (standard rectangular boxes etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Because the rectangle acts as a drawing object and not a text area Word has a hard time with these.  Will a text box work instead of a drawing object?  I was able to create a text box then insert a table and start a numbered list inside of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, which might certainly help me in the future. The problem with text boxes for the document I was working on is however that you can't create text boxes with rounded corners -- or at least not as far as I know ...

Comment: @Feirefiz, you can create rounded textboxes by creating an autoshape and adding text to it: http://www.fanhow.com/knowhow:Create_a_Text_Box_with_Rounded_Corners_in_Microsoft_Word_51913870